# Change date on icon click event

Tags: theming, javascript, datetime, tokens

I'm trying to create a custom block that display the current date (Only Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros and A full textual representation of the day of the week) using the tocken module.[image: LIke this]

Now my problem is how to change the date when the next, prev icon is cicked?
For example: Today is saturday the 05th. When i click next, i get sunday the 6th. And when i click prev, i get friday the 04th. 
Maybe this can be possible using javascript or php.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to go about this.

### Pure JS

You can send the date shown to the JavaScript either via drupal_add_js or as a data attribute and let the JavaScript manage the date changes. You would need to change the current date +/- 1 when clicking on a button and figure out the name of the day and the day number of the day and display that. This should be relative simple to do.

### AJAX

You can let the use AJAX and send the selected date to a custom menu callback which returns the markup for the new date.

Of the two solutions I would prefer the pure JS version. The Ajax version is more complex to implement and will generate a bigger load on the webserver. It could be a nice solution if you want to do advanced theming and don't want to place that logic in the JS (like weekends / holidays etc are displayed in different styles)